# Add Yoast breadcrumbs HTML to WordPress REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, yoast

I am using this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-yoast-meta/ to add Yoast meta data to the WP REST API response.

I can see that you can add custom data to this via:

```
/**
 * Add Yoast Breadcrumb HTML to the REST API
 */
function wpym_add_custom_meta_tag( $yoast_meta ) {
    $yoast_meta[] = array(
        'name'      => 'breadcrumbs',
        'content'   => 'TBC'
    );
    return $yoast_meta;
}
add_filter( 'wp_rest_yoast_meta/filter_yoast_meta', 'wpym_add_custom_meta_tag', 10, 1);
```

**Output:**

    `"yoast_meta": [
        {
            "name": "twitter:card",
            "content": "summary_large_image"
        },
        {
            "name": "twitter:title",
            "content": "Page title"
        },
        {
            "name": "breadcrumbs",
            "content": "TBC"
        }
    ],`

I cannot see a clear way to add breadcrumb HTML to this response. This would also obviously need to cater for all types of pages/post types/taxonomies etc just like the `yoast_breadcrumb` function.

If I add `yoast_breadcrumb('', '', false);` it just returns the home page link as thats the first entry.

Anyone got any ideas of how this could be achieved? I need this to implement on a React application front-end.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a way to do it Nathan?

Comment: @shwarp No, not as of yet :(